# Creating a spring batch step using spring data flow

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am implementing remote partitioning using spring batc.

I need to create a new batch job at first stage, and later on add steps to this job using spring data flow.

How can spring data flow create a new batch step and add it to an already exising batch job?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. What you can probably try is to add the step to your job definition, repackage your app and deploy it to SCDF with the same job name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I will be more clear: i need the SCDF task to get step parameters , create a step which is part of a job execution that has started not in this task instance

Comment: thanks for the clarification. In regards to "create a step which is part of a job execution that has started": AFAIK, it is not possible to dynamically add a step to a running job execution.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to add step exucution to a running job execution?

Comment: Meaning i will define a worker step but deynamcly on runtime define of its number of executions

Comment: That's different from the initial question. The [DeployerPartitionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/current/reference/html/batch-partitioning.html) is what you might be looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. and it is very helpful. I have just one small issue. the data which I will provide to the workers is very big (~70 M records) therefore, I will paginate.

Comment: In this example, EnvironmentVariablesProvider I assume is set with all the data the current worker needs, I guess a hash map, and In order to prepare this hash map I will need to go over all of the data (70 M) before I launch the first worker. Is there a clean way to dispatch to workers gradually?

Comment: Give each worker a partition metadata and let workers do the pagination, not the master.

Comment: I am thinking to implement as shown in below example as remote chunking - if spring data flow will allow it. can chunk be executed as spring data flow task?

Comment: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781783553372/8/ch08lvl1sec46/remote-chunking